# Discord bot Kick & Ban command not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm learning Javascript and decided to code a Discord bot but I can't make it kick or ban. I have tried a couple of different codes but all of them gave me error except for this one. The only problem is that it does nothing when I do the command in discord. Again if this is a noob error I am sorry but I'm learning

This is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require(`./config.json`);


const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Im online now');
});



client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ping`)) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}beep`)) {
        message.channel.send('Boop.');
    }
    else if (message.content === `${prefix}server`) {
        message.channel.send(`Server: ${message.guild.name}\ there is: ${message.guild.memberCount} in the server`);
    }
    else if (message.content === 'no u') {
        message.channel.send('no u')
    }
    }
)

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(`+kick)`)) {
    if(message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')){ 
    
      if(!message.mentions.users.size){
          return message.reply("Who am I supposed!");
         }
       var user= message.mentions.members.first();
       message.channel.send('<@{user.id}> has just been kicked');
       user.kick();
     }
      else {
              message.reply(message.channel.send('You cant do that'));
          }
          
  }
})


client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(`+ban)`)) {
    if(message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')){ 
    
      if(!message.mentions.users.size){
          return message.reply("Who am I supposed to ban?!");
         }
       var user= message.mentions.members.first();
       message.channel.send('<@{user.id}> Has just been banned');
       user.ban();
     }
      else {
              message.reply(message.channel.send('you cant do that'));
          }
          
  }
})


client.login(token);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one `Client#message` event per-bot.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but your code checks for the command `+ban)` and `+kick)`. Are you sure that extra ')' was on purpose? Cause this way you'd have to use the command as `+kick) @Toten#1234`. I'd guess you want the command to be `+kick @Toten#1234`, but that's merely a guess

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to the JavaScript and discord.js world! If you're a beginner, I strongly recommend you read the [official discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/).

Secondly, the `message.mentions.members.first` return an ID, and you have to put it in the parameter of the method `message.guild.member` if I'm not wrong.

That'll look like **this:**

```
let kickUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
```

For example, my kick command looks like **this:**

```
exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let kUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
    if (!kUser) return message.channel.send("Je n'ai pas trouvé l'utilisateur");
    let kReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Permission refusée");
    if (kUser.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Cette personne ne peut pas être kick !");

    if (!kReason) return message.channel.send("Tu n'a pas mentionné de raison");

    let kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription("Kick")
        .setColor("#ff750c")
        .setThumbnail(kUser.user.avatarURL())
        .addField("Utilisateur kick", `${kUser} ID : ${kUser.id}`)
        .addField("Kick par", `<@${message.author.id}> ID: ${message.author.id}`)
        .addField("Channel", message.channel)
        .addField("Date", message.createdAt)
        .addField("Raison", kReason);

    let kickchannel = bot.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === config.discord.modlogChannelID);
    if (!kickchannel) return message.channel.send("Je n'ai pas pu trouver le channel de modération (adm error)");

    message.guild.member(kUser).kick(kReason);
    message.delete();

    kickchannel.send(kickEmbed);
};
```

Hope that will help! (My code may not work with the new versions of discord.js because it is one year old and I didn't upgrade it, but the logic is here).

Comment: "Secondly, the message.mentions.members.first return an id, and you have to put it in parameter of the method message.guild.member if i'm not wrong". No, `message.mentions.members.first()` will work.